# Let $N\unlhd G$ with $[G:N]=3$. Find all non-trivial group homomorphisms $f:G\to\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ for $n=2,3,...,10$ with $N\le\ker(f)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group and $N$ a normal subgroup of $G$ with index 3, $[G:N]=3$. I need to find all non-trivial group homomorphisms $f:G\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n=2,3,...,10$ with $N\leq \text{ker}(f)$.

How do I do this, I have no idea how to even start? I mean for example taking $n=2$, I would have $\text{ker}(f)=2\mathbb{Z}$. Now I need to find a normal-subgroup of $2\mathbb{Z}$ with $[G:N]=3$ right? How do I do that?

Comment: You don't have $\ker(f)=n\mathbb Z$. This is not even a subgroup of $G$ (in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that any homomorphism $f\colon G\to \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with $N\le \ker(f)$ induces a homomorphism $\overline{f}\colon G/N\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ given by $\overline f(\overline g) = f(g)$, where $\overline g = gN$. What do you know about the group structure of $G/N$ and does that help you find all homomorphisms to $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for the given list of $n$s?

Comment: I know the theorem you are writing about, I also know the group structure of $G/N$ but I don't get how to get the homomorphisms. I know that such a homomorphism must be induced by mapping $0+N$ to $2Z$ right? I don't know more...

Comment: Since $G/N\cong \mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, the problem reduces to finding all group homomorphisms $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Do you agree?

Comment: Ok.. I agree yes. But are there for all $n$?